# Pass A Generic (Template) Class For Runtime Initialization

Tags: c#, templates, generics, runtime

Right now I have a database which initializes a whole bunch of card types as follows:

```
private void LoadCardTypes()
{
    database.cardTypeList.Clear();
    database.cardTypeMap.Clear();
    Object[] assets = Resources.LoadAll("ScriptableObjects/CardTypes", typeof(Object)) as Object[];
    if (showLog) Debug.Log("Loading CardTypes");
    foreach (Object asset in assets)
    {
        M_CardPlayType type = (M_CardPlayType)asset;

        if (type.name.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("WARNING: Object Mapped Without Name");
        }

        CheckIdCollision(type, database.cardMap);
        VerifyIdExists(type, CardPlayTypes.SINGLETON);

        database.cardTypeList.Add(type);
        database.cardTypeMap.Add(type.id, type);
    }
}
```

Where the code goes `M_CardPlayType type = (M_CardPlayType)asset;` I'd like to make it a template type.

I want it to be something like

```
private void LoadCardTypes(Type<T> WhateverType)
{
  //other code
  WhateverType type = (WhateverType)asset;
  //other code
  VerifyIdExists(type, WhateverType.SINGLETON);
}
```

Can this be done? (And bonus question if there is a technique what is it called?).

**Update working except 1 part**

New signature is

```
private void LoadNewCardTypes<T,P>(DictionaryOfIntAndSerializableObject map, List<T> list, string path) where T : M_Object where P : ID
```

My P is giving me trouble. Here is my ID class

```
public class ID
{
    protected string _className = "ID";
    protected static ID _singleton = new ID();

    public static ID SINGLETON
    {
        get { return _singleton; }
    }
}
```

When I try to get the singleton from P I get an error (it can't find it)

```
P.SINGLETON//doesnt work
```

Do you know why my singleton isn't working in this context?

**Final solution thanks to @kailanjian**

```
private void LoadNewCardTypes<T,P>(DictionaryOfIntAndSerializableObject map, List<T> list, string path) where T : M_Object where P : ID
{
    map.Clear();
    list.Clear();
    Object[] assets = Resources.LoadAll(path, typeof(Object)) as Object[];
    if (showLog) Debug.Log("Loading " + path + " types");
    foreach (Object asset in assets)
    {
        T type = (T)asset;

        if (type.name.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("WARNING: Object Mapped Without Name");
        }

        CheckIdCollision(type, map);
        VerifyIdExists(type, (P)ID.SINGLETON);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void LoadCardTypes<T>() where T : ParentClass
{
    //other code
    T type = (T)asset;
    //other code
    VerifyIdExists(type, T.SINGLETON);
}
```

`ParentClass` is the type that you guarantee is inherited/implemented by any type `T` you pass. It should have the `SINGLETON` value as one of its values for you to be able to use it.

Source: [MSDN Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Comment: Did you include the `where` statement with a parent class that can pass down a value called `SINGLETON`? That is really important, otherwise the C# type checker won't let you run.

Comment: Yes, Im noticing it lets me access member variables but not static class functions. E.g. if I add `public int test = 1` it finds P.id. But it can't find the `P.SINGLETON` static call.

Comment: Correction: I believe static values cannot be passed down, but you can easily call it from the parent e.g. ID.SINGLETON

Comment: Bingo `VerifyIdExists(type, (P)ID.SINGLETON);`